# CSS flexible elements layout: fixed left position but sink down to avoid overlapping?

Tags: html, css, css-float, overlapping

I am trying to build a layout when I have a list of labels starting at some fixed percentage position, but I want them to push down on separate lines if page becomes narrow to avoid their overlap:

```
|        |<- 10%   |<-20%     |
label1   label2    label3

|    |    |    |
label1
     label2
          label3
```

So far I could not do that (tried floats, spacer divs, spans) and I begin to think that this may be impossible because of how the rendering flows.

Do you know if there is a solution, or what I could do otherwise? Here is my cleaned up [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexandroid/pyMFh/) template.

Comment: You might be able to use jQuery to check the size of the screen  `$(window).resize()` and manipulate your divs accordingly. Worth giving a try I think.

Comment: Yeah, looks like that would be a way to go for me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way that occurs to me is with a media query. You would have to hardcode the specific screen with at which you want the "jump" to happen. I'm afraid there is no way to do this in a smart and automated way with CSS only.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 35em) {
    .d2 {margin-top: 1em;}
    .d3 {margin-top: 2em;}
}
```

You can see an example here http://jsfiddle.net/wPrq8/

Comment: Interesting, I will explore @media more, thank you! Looks like in general case I will need to use Javascript to detect overlaps - unfortunately my category labels have different widths and offsets, so there would be many combinations of screen widths to prepare this way. But, in my case hiding the labels for narrow screen would work too, so I may simply do that instead.

Answer (score 0):

To get close to that behavior with pure css would [require them to be floated](http://jsfiddle.net/pyMFh/4/). However, if your intent is to get them to all move down at once, then I have not yet found a way to make that happen.

Comment: Yes, looks like I will have to use JS and switch styles in runtime.